# Get the neighboring states of a given USA state

Tags: sql-server, geolocation, geospatial, geography, opendata

I created the SQL table with the US states using this page: http://www.john.geek.nz/2009/01/sql-tips-list-of-us-states/

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsaStates] (
    [Code] CHAR (2)     NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UsaStates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Code] ASC)
);
```

I created another SQL table called "NeighborStates" with 2 columns: State and NeighborState.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NeighborStates](
    [StateCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [NeighborStateCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NeighborStates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StateCode] ASC,
    [NeighborStateCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NeighborStates]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NeighborStates_NeighborStates_Neighbors] FOREIGN KEY([NeighborStateCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UsaStates] ([Code])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NeighborStates]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NeighborStates_UsaStates] FOREIGN KEY([StateCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UsaStates] ([Code])
GO
```

But now, I'm looking for some geospatial data or even a hard-coded list (list of neighbors states for each state) to fill my table "NeighborStates".

Do you know where to find a datasource with the neighboring states of a given USA state?

```
INSERT INTO [NeighborStates](StateCode,NeighborStateCode) ???
```

Comment: I updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to check if the state of Boston and the state of NYC share a border.
My internet-research led me to this dataset

**http://state.1keydata.com/bordering-states-list.php**

The page lists bordering states for each of the 50 states in the United States. You can view the information either alphabetically by state or by the number of bordering states.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is so strongly in the direction of the fact that you will be unable to find such a public data source that I'm posting as an answer rather than as a comment that "I don't think there is one."  Just pull out a map and write up your own, it should take you...  half hour or so?

And honestly, if what you're doing you or your company plans to make money on, this CAN be a good thing.  You can either open-source it for "the next guy" or you can make money off of the barrier to entry in that you had to create something not technologically difficult but something that took building.

Comment: Based on your opinion-request, the asker made a publicly accessible dataset open sourced at https://github.com/ubikuity/List-of-neighboring-states-for-each-US-state

Answer (score 0):

Just hoping to save someone else the time from having to make this list:

```
CREATE TABLE StateNeighbor(state varchar(50),stateabbr char(2),neighborstate varchar(50),neighborstateabbr char(2))

INSERT Into StateNeighbor(state,stateabbr,neighborstate,neighborstateabbr)
VALUES
('Alabama','AL','Florida','FL'),
('Alabama','AL','Georgia','GA'),
('Alabama','AL','Mississippi','MS'),
('Alabama','AL','Tennessee','TN'),
('Alaska','AK','',''),
('Arizona','AZ','California','CA'),
('Arizona','AZ','Colorado','CO'),
('Arizona','AZ','Nevada','NV'),
('Arizona','AZ','New Mexico','NM'),
('Arizona','AZ','Utah','UT'),
('Arkansas','AR','Louisiana','LA'),
('Arkansas','AR','Mississippi','MS'),
('Arkansas','AR','Missouri','MO'),
('Arkansas','AR','Oklahoma','OK'),
('Arkansas','AR','Tennessee','TN'),
('Arkansas','AR','Texas','TX'),
('California','CA','Arizona','AZ'),
('California','CA','Nevada','NV'),
('California','CA','Oregon','OR'),
('Colorado','CO','Arizona','AZ'),
('Colorado','CO','Kansas','KS'),
('Colorado','CO','Nebraska','NE'),
('Colorado','CO','New Mexico','NM'),
('Colorado','CO','Oklahoma','OK'),
('Colorado','CO','Utah','UT'),
('Colorado','CO','Wyoming','WY'),
('Connecticut','CT','Massachusetts','MA'),
('Connecticut','CT','New York','NY'),
('Connecticut','CT','Rhode Island','RI'),
('Delaware','DE','Maryland','MD'),
('Delaware','DE','New Jersey','NJ'),
('Delaware','DE','Pennsylvania','PA'),
('Florida','FL','Alabama','AL'),
('Florida','FL','Georgia','GA'),
('Georgia','GA','Alabama','AL'),
('Georgia','GA','Florida','FL'),
('Georgia','GA','North Carolina','NC'),
('Georgia','GA','South Carolina','SC'),
('Georgia','GA','Tennessee','TN'),
('Hawaii','HI','',''),
('Idaho','ID','Montana','MT'),
('Idaho','ID','Nevada','NV'),
('Idaho','ID','Oregon','OR'),
('Idaho','ID','Utah','UT'),
('Idaho','ID','Washington','WA'),
('Idaho','ID','Wyoming','WY'),
('Illinois','IL','Indiana','IN'),
('Illinois','IL','Iowa','IA'),
('Illinois','IL','Michigan','MI'),
('Illinois','IL','Kentucky','KY'),
('Illinois','IL','Missouri','MO'),
('Illinois','IL','Wisconsin','WI'),
('Indiana','IN','Illinois','IL'),
('Indiana','IN','Kentucky','KY'),
('Indiana','IN','Michigan','MI'),
('Indiana','IN','Ohio','OH'),
('Iowa','IA','Illinois','IL'),
('Iowa','IA','Minnesota','MN'),
('Iowa','IA','Missouri','MO'),
('Iowa','IA','Nebraska','NE'),
('Iowa','IA','South Dakota','SD'),
('Iowa','IA','Wisconsin','WI'),
('Kansas','KS','Colorado','Co'),
('Kansas','KS','Missouri','MO'),
('Kansas','KS','Nebraska','NE'),
('Kansas','KS','Oklahoma','OK'),
('Kentucky','KY','Illinois','IL'),
('Kentucky','KY','Indiana','IN'),
('Kentucky','KY','Missouri','MO'),
('Kentucky','KY','Ohio','OH'),
('Kentucky','KY','Tennessee','TN'),
('Kentucky','KY','Virginia','VA'),
('Kentucky','KY','West Virginia','WV'),
('Louisiana','LA','Arkansas','AR'),
('Louisiana','LA','Mississippi','MS'),
('Louisiana','LA','Texas','TX'),
('Maine','ME','New Hampshire','NH'),
('Maryland','MD','Delaware','DE'),
('Maryland','MD','Pennsylvania','PA'),
('Maryland','MD','Virginia','VA'),
('Maryland','MD','West Virginia','WV'),
('Massachusetts','MA','Connecticut','CT'),
('Massachusetts','MA','New Hampshire','NH'),
('Massachusetts','MA','New York','NY'),
('Massachusetts','MA','Rhode Island','RI'),
('Massachusetts','MA','Vermont','VT'),
('Michigan','MI','Illinois','IL'),
('Michigan','MI','Indiana','IN'),
('Michigan','MI','Minnesota','MN'),
('Michigan','MI','Ohio','OH'),
('Michigan','MI','Wisconsin','WI'),
('Minnesota','MN','Iowa','IA'),
('Minnesota','MN','Michigan','MI'),
('Minnesota','MN','North Dakota','ND'),
('Minnesota','MN','South Dakota','SD'),
('Minnesota','MN','Wisconsin','WI'),
('Mississippi','MS','Alabama','AL'),
('Mississippi','MS','Arkansas','AR'),
('Mississippi','MS','Louisiana','LA'),
('Mississippi','MS','Tennessee','TN'),
('Missouri','MO','Arkansas','AR'),
('Missouri','MO','Illinois','IL'),
('Missouri','MO','Iowa','IA'),
('Missouri','MO','Kansas','KS'),
('Missouri','MO','Kentucky','KY'),
('Missouri','MO','Nebraska','NE'),
('Missouri','MO','Oklahoma','OK'),
('Missouri','MO','Tennessee','TN'),
('Montana','MT','Idaho','ID'),
('Montana','MT','North Dakota','ND'),
('Montana','MT','South Dakota','SD'),
('Montana','MT','Wyoming','WY'),
('Nebraska','NE','Colorado','CO'),
('Nebraska','NE','Iowa','IA'),
('Nebraska','NE','Kansas','KS'),
('Nebraska','NE','Missouri','MO'),
('Nebraska','NE','South Dakota','SD'),
('Nebraska','NE','Wyoming','WY'),
('Nevada','NV','Arizona','AZ'),
('Nevada','NV','California','CA'),
('Nevada','NV','Idaho','ID'),
('Nevada','NV','Oregon','OR'),
('Nevada','NV','Utah','UT'),
('New Hampshire','NH','Maine','ME'),
('New Hampshire','NH','Massachusetts','MA'),
('New Hampshire','NH','Vermont','VT'),
('New Jersey','NJ','Delaware','DE'),
('New Jersey','NJ','New York','NY'),
('New Jersey','NJ','Pennsylvania','PA'),
('New Mexico','NM','Arizona','AZ'),
('New Mexico','NM','Colorado','CO'),
('New Mexico','NM','Oklahoma','OK'),
('New Mexico','NM','Texas','TX'),
('New Mexico','NM','Utah','UT'),
('New York','NY','Connecticut','CT'),
('New York','NY','Massachusetts','MA'),
('New York','NY','New Jersey','NJ'),
('New York','NY','Pennsylvania','PA'),
('New York','NY','Rhode Island','RI'),
('New York','NY','Vermont','VT'),
('North Carolina','NC','Georgia','GA'),
('North Carolina','NC','South Carolina','SC'),
('North Carolina','NC','Tennessee','TN'),
('North Carolina','NC','Virginia','VA'),
('North Dakota','ND','Minnesota','MN'),
('North Dakota','ND','Montana','MT'),
('North Dakota','ND','South Dakota','SD'),
('Ohio','OH','Indiana','IN'),
('Ohio','OH','Kentucky','KY'),
('Ohio','OH','Michigan','MI'),
('Ohio','OH','Pennsylvania','PA'),
('Ohio','OH','West Virginia','WV'),
('Oklahoma','OK','Arkansas','AR'),
('Oklahoma','OK','Colorado','CO'),
('Oklahoma','OK','Kansas','KS'),
('Oklahoma','OK','Missouri','MO'),
('Oklahoma','OK','New Mexico','NM'),
('Oklahoma','OK','Texas','TX'), 
('Oregon','OR','California','CA'),
('Oregon','OR','Idaho','ID'),
('Oregon','OR','Nevada','NV'),
('Oregon','OR','Washington','WA'),
('Pennsylvania','PA','Delaware','DE'),
('Pennsylvania','PA','Maryland','MD'),
('Pennsylvania','PA','New Jersey','NJ'),
('Pennsylvania','PA','New York','NY'),
('Pennsylvania','PA','Ohio','OH'),
('Pennsylvania','PA','West Virginia','WV'),
('Rhode Island','RI','Connecticut','CT'),
('Rhode Island','RI','Massachusetts','MA'),
('Rhode Island','RI','New York','NY'),
('South Carolina','SC','Georgia','GA'),
('South Carolina','SC','North Carolina','NC'),
('South Dakota','SD','Iowa','IA'),
('South Dakota','SD','Minnesota','MN'),
('South Dakota','SD','Montana','MT'),
('South Dakota','SD','Nebraska','NE'),
('South Dakota','SD','North Dakota','ND'),
('South Dakota','SD','Wyoming','WY'),
('Tennessee','TN','Alabama','AL'),
('Tennessee','TN','Arkansas','AR'),
('Tennessee','TN','Georgia','GA'),
('Tennessee','TN','Kentucky','KY'),
('Tennessee','TN','Mississippi','MS'),
('Tennessee','TN','Missouri','MO'),
('Tennessee','TN','North Carolina','NC'),
('Tennessee','TN','Virginia','VA'),
('Texas','TX','Arkansas','AR'),
('Texas','TX','Louisiana','LA'),
('Texas','TX','New Mexico','NM'),
('Texas','TX','Oklahoma','OK'),
('Utah','UT','Arizona','AZ'),
('Utah','UT','Colorado','CO'),
('Utah','UT','Idaho','ID'),
('Utah','UT','Nevada','NV'),
('Utah','UT','New Mexico','NM'),
('Utah','UT','Wyoming','WY'),
('Vermont','VT','Massachusetts','MA'),
('Vermont','VT','New Hampshire','NH'),
('Vermont','VT','New York','NY'),
('Virginia','VA','Kentucky','KY'),
('Virginia','VA','Maryland','MD'),
('Virginia','VA','North Carolina','NC'),
('Virginia','VA','Tennessee','TN'),
('Virginia','VA','West Virginia','WV'),
('Washington','WA','Idaho','ID'),
('Washington','WA','Oregon','OR'),
('West Virginia','WV','Kentucky','KY'),
('West Virginia','WV','Maryland','MD'),
('West Virginia','WV','Ohio','OH'),
('West Virginia','WV','Pennsylvania','PA'),
('West Virginia','WV','Virginia','VA'),
('Wisconsin','WI','Illinois','IL'),
('Wisconsin','WI','Iowa','IA'),
('Wisconsin','WI','Michigan','MI'),
('Wisconsin','WI','Minnesota','MN'),
('Wyoming','WY','Colorado','CO'),
('Wyoming','WY','Idaho','ID'),
('Wyoming','WY','Montana','MT'),
('Wyoming','WY','Nebraska','NE'),
('Wyoming','WY','South Dakota','SD'),
('Wyoming','WY','Utah','UT');
```